# placing a figure made of subfigures inside an enumerate environment

Tags: floats, enumerate, subfloats, minipage

I am writing a document, where I answer a set of numbered questions, and some answers include figures made of `subfigures`. I list the answers in an `enumerate` environment, and I want the graphics relating to a specific question to be before the next `\item`.

I will provide an example, where this is NOT the case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item1 \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap1}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap3}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{main caption}
\end{figure}

\item item2 \blindtext
\item item3 \blindtext
\item item4\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This will place the figure somewhere in the middle of the third `item`. The solution I know for a situation like this is to use a `minipage`. I know minipages don't go well with the `figure` environment, so I ditched it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item1 \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{subfigure}{subcap1}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\captionof{figure}{main caption}

\end{minipage}


\item item2 \blindtext
\item item3 \blindtext
\item item4\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This, unfortunately, does not build:

```
! Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
```

I am guessing this a float vs minipage issue, but I have no idea how to solve this ... Any suggestions?

Comment: the only reason to use `figure` is to specify that content as a float which is _not_ part of the main document flow, and can be moved to help page breaking. (using `[h]` increases the chance of the figure going to the end of the document as it prevents the float being placed on float pages as it removes `p`) If you want an image to be part of a list, just use `\includegraphics` directly.

Comment: My issue is that I have four images, which I want to place as subimages in a 2by2 and have captions for each. A simple includegraphics will not help me with this.

Comment: you could use `[H]` (from the float package)  to make it not float or (possibly more reasonably as a non-floating float is a contradiction) just use a minipage and if you want captions use `\captionof{}` from the `capt-of` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you (a) encase the four `subfigure` environments in a `figure` environment and (b) write either `[ht!]` or `[H]` as the positioning specifier. If this produces a page break immediately *after* the `figure`, you'll need to insert a `\clearpage` statement before the figure, so that the figure and associated `\item` are on the same page.

In addition, since you've indicated that the figures should occur immediately before the associated enumerated `\item`, I also suggest setting `\intextsep` to 0pt, to snug up the distance between the figure and the next \item.

Observe that I've added five [5!] `\centering` instructions to your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float} %for "[H]" positioning specifier

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt} 
\item item1 \blindtext 

\vspace{1cm} % create some vertical separation
\begin{figure}[ht!] % or: [H]
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap2}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{subcap4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{main caption}
\end{figure}

\item item2 \blindtext
\item item3 \blindtext
\item item4\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `[H]` did the trick, thanks! Why did you add 5 `\centering`? I don't really get what they are doing.

Comment: @fbence - The `\centering` instructions inside each `subfigure` are needed because the widths of the minipages exceed those of the graphs (3cm). Try it without those 4 `\centering` directives: You'll immediately notice that the graphs are centered above the captions. The first `\centering` directive, right after `\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}`, is needed to ensure that the group of 4 graphs is nicely centered above the overall figure caption.